# How does Windows 10 access files to which it has no pathway?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, data-recovery

So this is certainly not the best way to phrase this question but here is my situation:
I tried the upgrade to Windows 10 on my main machine roughly a year ago and quickly decided it was not for me, reverting to 7.
Recently I've been toying with different OS through virtualization and created a virtual drive with a clean install of 7 to update to 10 a second time to mess around without compromising my main system.
I was immediately concerned to learn that after the clean install of 7 updated to 10 it had access to all of my desktop backgrounds from last year.

My question is essentially: Where is Microsoft storing this information?

It's possible that it was through an Outlook account but I have never uploaded those files there - I triple checked.  It is also possible that they were retrieved from my main machine as those files still exist there but it was my understanding that the entire point of virtualization was that there could be no communication between systems without explicit permissions.

How have these files been retrieved?

(they are being stored in `RoamedThemeFiles\DesktopBackground` but that's basically all I know)

Comment: Did you have a Microsoft Account on any of those Installations?

Comment: I believe in 2016 having an Outlook account is the same thing as having a Microsoft account.  Though as I've said, I did not knowingly upload that data nor can I find any indication on my account that they have stored it.

Comment: Microsoft will sync data across accounts- how did you log in to your Outlook account? Via MS Outlook, or the Mail App, or?

Comment: Via the Mail App I believe but is that relevant? You're suggesting that Microsoft kept a copy of my background photos (and God knows what else) server side for over a year without my request? For what purpose?

Comment: I believe that this is what happened: You logged into the Mail App, which counts as a sign into your microsoft account in Windows 10. As per MS Account T&Cs etc your data was then synced up to the cloud so it was available when you next logged and everything was familiar. When you re-logged, it pulled the data down and synced.

When Win10 counts it as a MS Acc. login it syncs quite a lot of data.